# Why didn't T'Challa tell Shuri about the existence of this character?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-wakanda-forever

In *Black Panther: Wakanda Forever* T'Challa's death is addressed and

> after Queen Ramonda's death, Shuri becomes the head of the family, as well as the Black Panther.

During the first mid-credits scene, it turns out that

> Prior to his death, T'Challa sired a son with Nakia, whom they apltly named, T'Challa.

This character was kept secret from all, except

> Queen Ramonda.

Even Shuri didn't know.

I'd like to know

> **why T'Challa and Nakia didn't tell Shuri, even though they told Queen Ramonda?**

Why didn't T'Challa tell Shuri about the existence of this character?

Comment: At worst this is opinions and at best a future work and in reality just so it was more dramatic.  Unless Shuri could be notoriously bad at secrets  despite the  statement she is good.

Comment: She'd put it in the vault, of course!

Comment: From a real world perspective, given Shuri's grief, telling her about her nephew probably would have defeated the purpose of raising him away from Wakanda, as Shuri may have focussed on him.

Comment: Yes, this disturbed me too. I can see the value in not blabbing this to the international community, but hiding this from your little sister?

Answer (score 6):

As Nakia explains to Shuri, **T'Challa wanted his son to have a normal life, far from the turbulences of royal life in Wakanda**. That's the reason why Nakia left Wakanda to secretly raise their son in another country.

Why did he tell his mother and not his younger sister? We may never know. He may have told his mother because keeping a secret from her was too hard, or knowing his incoming death, he needed someone powerful to protect his son in case of danger.

He may have been lacking time to tell Shuri about her nephew. Remember that Queen Ramonda was about to tell Shuri "something important about T'Challa" right before Namor appeared before them for the first time. She was probably about to speak about T'Challa Jr.